# MFC Dialog - How to resize and re-set client 'view' rect?

Tags: mfc, dialog

I have a dialog and I want a 'mini' version of it for a cut-down version of its functionality. I could make another dialog template / class, but I wondered if there was a way to change the size of my dialog and move the client rect 'view' so I can only see some of the controls (that aren't at the top-left of the full size dialog. Then I can just reuse the template and code I already have

So to go from this:

[image: Full size dialog]

to something like this:

[image: Mini dialog]

Comment: Sure, it's possible to modify a dialog resource after it has been created from a resource. Though 'scrolling' part of it out of view won't be sufficient. The invisible parts would still contribute to the dialog's keyboard interface. You would have to hide and disable those controls, and reposition the visible ones.

Comment: Ahh - yes, I forgot about the tab order shizz. Probably easier to make a separate dialog, and just centralise the common code.

Comment: The tab order won't get in your way for controls that are disabled. You just have to make sure that those invisible controls are disabled, and you can reuse a single dialog template resource.

Comment: OK - so its just the same as scrolling the dialog? (However that is done?)

Comment: You can show/hide windows using `ShowWindow`. You can enable/disable windows using `EnableWindow`. You can reposition/resize windows using `MoveWindow`. When disabling a window make sure to move input focus to the next enabled window. Otherwise the dialog will cease to respond to keyboard input. I don't know whether returning `TRUE` from [OnInitDialog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cdialog-class#oninitdialog) is sufficient to skip over disabled controls, or whether you have to explicitly set input focus from there.